# Web-scraping | Get lat-long from mapbox map

Tags: html, google-chrome, web-scraping

Thank you in advance for helping me out.

At this link https://www.cityscoot.eu/en/paris/ there is mapbox map which show the locations of available motorcycles, I want to get the lat,long on these points.

There are other posts but those belongs to google maps and I am looking for mapbox.

I looked into the chrome-inspector but couldn't find the source of these lat-long.

Can anyone please tell me how to find them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple POST request. Maybe it's an open API and you can also get the data. In the Inspector click the Network Tab to see all Requests made by a Website.

[image]

[image]